# Hibernate one-to-many list with list index as part of the key

Tags: hibernate, list, indexing, annotations, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  -- some other columns
  CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
);

CREATE TABLE product_image
(
  product_id bigint NOT NULL,
  order integer NOT NULL,
  width integer NOT NULL,
  -- some other columns
  CONSTRAINT product_image_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id , order ),
  CONSTRAINT product_image_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
  REFERENCES product (id) 
);
```

that I want to map like this:

```
public class Product {
  ...
  List<Image> images;
  ...
}

public class Image {
  ...
  int width;
  ...
}
```

Basically, I want the Product class to have a list of Image objects that contain all the fields from the image table except the order and the product id (if thats possible). The list should be sorted according to the order field.

Ideally, I don't want to have to deal with the order at all. I just want hibernate to use the order from the list in Product. Do I need product and order fields in the image class?

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how my annotations should like or what the best way is to map this sort of thing? I can't really do anything in the database but i'm open about the java model.

Thanks!

Edit:

I tried this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_image")
public class Image implements Comparable<Image>{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order")
    private Integer order;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    private Product product;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = Image.class)
    @OrderColumn(name = "order")
    private List<Image> images;
}
```

It works for reading data but this code Fails:

```
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
Image i = new Image();
i.setProduct(product);
images.add(i);      
product.setImages(images);

session.save(product);
```

because order is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports Sorted collections like `java.util.SortedMap` and `java.util.SortedSet`. And the annotation @Sort allows you to set the compartor for sorting. [Check out the reference document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted).

First define your own Comparator class for sorting. Override the `compare` method to sort the Set based on `order` value in your `Image` class.

```
class ImageComparator<Image> implements Comparator<Image> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Image o1, Image o2) {
        // implement compare method
    }
}
```

Once thats done define your `Product` class with `@Sort` annotations to include your custom comparator `ImageComparator` class.

```
public class Product {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = ImageComparator.class)
    SortedSet<Image> images;
    ...
}
```

Now you will have your `images` list sorted.

Comment: So you're saying that i need an explicit order field in the Image class, that I can use for sorting?

Comment: My understanding is that You want to sort by `order` field in Image table.

Comment: Yes, but I don't really want the image to know about its index in the image list of the product. Is that possible?

Comment: Declare the `order` as private in Image class and don't provide any setters to `order`. Then instead of a separate Comparator class, implement `Comparator` and override `compare` method in Image class itself. So that `order` will not be accesable from Image class.

Comment: And then hibernate is setting the field according to the list index, when I add an object to the list? (sorry for the question, but I can't try it out right now)